# How can I check to see if a Dojo dialog is loaded?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dialog, gis, esri

I am running a function that needs to close a Dojo dialog if it is loaded.  How do I check if a dojo dialog is running?  Do I use pure JavaScript and check by id if it is undefined?

```
if (dijit.byId("blah") !== undefined) { 
     destroyRecursive dijit;
}
```

Or do I use a property of the dialog object like:

```
isFocusable method
isLoaded property
```

Comment: This is the end function:
function bufferAddress(xCoord, yCoord) {
    if (dijit.byId("selectLocationDlg") !== undefined) {
        dijit.byId("selectLocationDlg").destroyRecursive();
    }
   // some other code here
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dialog provides two properties](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.2/dijit.Dialog) you might want to check: `isLoaded` and `open`. By digging the code you'll find the following descriptions:

- open: True if Dialog is currently displayed on screen.
- isLoaded: True if the ContentPane has data in it, either specified during initialization (via href or inline content), or set via attr('content', ...) / attr('href', ...) False if it doesn't have any content, or if ContentPane is still in the process of downloading href.

So, you could just:

```
var dialog = dijit.byId("blah");
if( dialog.open ) {
    dialog.destroy();
}
```

Comment: 8yrs later, you should use `if (dialog && dialog.open)` or some other safe-check that `dialog` exists (`typeof(dialog) != 'undefined'`, `dialog != null`, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to hide it or destroy it?

If you just want to show/hide it you can do the following:

```
var dialog = dijit.byId('blah');
if (dialog) {
  if (dialog.open) {
    dialog.hide();
  }
  else {
     dialog.show();
  }
}
```

If you wanted to destory it to free up memory:

```
var dialog = dijit.byId('blah');
dialog.destory();
```

I think `destroy` is recursive since it calls its parent `destroy` method and one of its parents is `dijit.layout.ContentPane`.